# What is the add method accepting an instance of Vector3()?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was just checking out the three.js examples page and I basically came across **[this](http://threejs.org/examples/?q=bird#canvas_geometry_birds)** example. Now if I check the code **[here](http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_birds.html)**, at the beginning of the js code there is the following code:

```
                var vector = new THREE.Vector3(),
                _acceleration, _width = 500, _height = 500, _depth = 200, _goal, _neighborhoodRadius = 100,
                _maxSpeed = 4, _maxSteerForce = 0.1, _avoidWalls = false;

                this.position = new THREE.Vector3();
                this.velocity = new THREE.Vector3();
                _acceleration = new THREE.Vector3();
```

As you can see there are four variables here that are an instance of `THREE.Vector3()`

A bit further into the code I see something like below:

```
_acceleration.add( vector );
```

Now if I check the documentation of the add method **[here](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=vect#Reference/Math/Vector3.add)**. I see the following:

> .add ( v ) this
>
> Adds v to this vector.

But I still don't understand what the below line of code is doing:

```
 _acceleration.add( vector );
```

I basically just want to get a hang of what really is happening in the above code.

Comment: Simple math ! adding vectors, for more details please refer to http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/adding-and-subtracting-vectors.html

Comment: You need that to move a particle from Position1 to Position 2 !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH super thanks . sorry new to three.js  so guess i need to start learning the basic stuff :)

Comment: You are welcome and good luck :)